# How to SubView a ViewController into a SubView of another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have two  `ViewController`.

One `ViewControllers` contain a `UITableView`. And another contains a `UIButton`.

I have created a `SubView` Programmatically.Now i want to `SubView` the `ViewController` which contains the `UITableView` in other when i Press UIButton.

I searched all over the net but cannot find any stable solution.

Currently i am trying this:

```
   bodyView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,120,containerView.frame.size.width,120)];

bodyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

CustomTableVC *tableVC = [[CustomTableVC alloc]init];

[tableVC willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[bodyView addSubview:tableVC.view];
[self addChildViewController:tableVC];
[tableVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[containerView addSubview:bodyView];
```

Comment: Is that a tableviewController? get the table from tableviewcontroller by `tableViewController.tableView` the add it as subview to your viewcontroller like: `[viewController.view addSubview:tableViewController.tableView]`;

Comment: no @Oyeoj it is a view Controller

Comment: Then get the view of the viewcontroller by `toAddViewController.view` like `parentViewController.view addSubview:toAddViewController.view`

Comment: you can not subview a view controller into subview of another view controller

Comment: You cannot `subview` a viewController but `.view` of the viewcontroller YES..

Comment: subview is not a verb. Do you mean add as a subview? And what is wrong with the solution you currently have? You haven't said what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

You can only use the `view` property of your `UIViewController` to assign into UIView associated in your second `UIViewController` which is not recommended because UIViewController as per MVC pattern holds lot controller stuff which includes populating the view and resolving the inputs/touch, which is an overhead in your (using multiple of viewcontrollers without needed) case.

You need to use one `UIViewController`. Add UITableView only in it, and UIButton only in it. **You only use one controller and multiple views.**

The other approach, if you do not want to change your code, may also use `ContainerView`. But in that case you need to create separate ViewControllers for UIButton and UITableView. And if you want to fetch data inbetween the ViewControllers, that will be a huge pain and also a bad software design with so much coupling and less encapsulation.

Comment: so how can i subview the table view in another vc

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this one and it's working for me.

```
@IBAction func moveToOther() { 


var otherController = OtherViewController()

        var bodyView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,120, self.view.frame.size.width, 120))
        bodyView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
        bodyView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        let tblCntrl = UITableViewController()
        bodyView.addSubview(tblCntrl.tableView)
        bodyView.clipsToBounds = true
        otherController.addChildViewController(tblCntrl)
        tblCntrl.didMoveToParentViewController(otherController)

        otherController.view.addSubview(bodyView)

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(otherController, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one view controller that contains both the table view & UIButton.
By default hide the table view. 
Just hide the button and show the table view when the button is clicked.